# Hiding the android keyboard for EditText

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Whenever I click in the `EditText` the Android keyboard popup window appears, but I don't want the keyboard to pop up.

I want to permanently hide the android keyboard popup for my current application.

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at this [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) which provides an explanation using [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: I think my solution can help.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/21480217/2127930

Answer (score 28):

Setting the flag `textIsSelectable` to `true` disables the soft keyboard.

You can set it in your xml layout like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    ...
    android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
```

Or programmatically, like this:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

The cursor will still be present, you'll be able to `select/copy/cut/paste` but the soft keyboard will never show.

Comment: Tried hundreds of solution, but this is the only one really working for me. And it's the simplest. Thanks!!

Comment: This is the perfect solution

Comment: Yes, its not  working in Android 8+, can we have any other alternative solution for this?? which can be done in xml??

Comment: Doesn't work on Android 12

Answer (score 12):

You may try to fake your EditText with a Button like this:

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/edit_birthday"
     style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="@string/hint_birthday"/>
```

Comment: This is better than the other solutions because the keyboard doesn't show at all here. In the other cases, you can see the keyboard popping up for an instance before popping back down.

Comment: it does work, but it stays pressed after single tap. how to avoid that?

Comment: @ImanAkbari by setting focusable="false", it doesn't stay pressed.

Answer (score 10):

In the manifest:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
       .
       .
       .
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
   </activity>
```

Comment: This appears to only affect if the keyboard is displayed when the activity first gets focus.  Per the official documentation, "The state of the soft keyboard — whether it is hidden or visible — when the activity becomes the focus of user attention".  It does not suppress the keyboard when pressing the EditText.

Answer (score 7):

Works for all Android versions.

In your XML use the property `android:textIsSelectable="true"`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    .
    .
    .
    android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
```

And, in your Java class:

```
editText1.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

In Kotlin:

```
editText1.showSoftInputOnFocus = false
```

Comment: setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false) works for me. Thx. (in Android 9)

Answer (score 5):

Solution can be found [here](http://tips4softwaredevelopment.blogspot.fr/2012/04/android-how-to-hide-keyboard-while.html) :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
      public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
         if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getApplicationWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
         }
         return false;
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These two line should do what you want:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Not working at all... the keyboard pops like any other time... do you do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 public void disableSoftKeyboard(final EditText v) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
                v.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                v.setTextIsSelectable(true);
            } else {
                v.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                v.setFocusable(true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in yout `onCreate()` method.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Not tested but It Should work!!

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file you can use this:

```
android:editable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your xml set attribute editable to false.
it won't let you edit the text and the keyboard will not be opened.

```
<EditText
     android:editable="false"
 />
```