# Hide Android soft keyboard and only allow digits on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard, android-inputtype

I have a custom keyboard and don't want to show the Android softkeyboard. this can be achieved by the following code ([How to hide Android soft keyboard on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997225/how-to-hide-android-soft-keyboard-on-edittext)):

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

However the EditText should only allow digits. this can be achieved by:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

I can't seem to find a way to combine both functionalities. setting the inputtype to TYPE_NULL will allow non-numeric characters when using hardware keyboards and setting the inputtype to TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER causes the soft keyboard to pop up.

Comment: This code may help you `input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);`

Comment: I tried it but it still shows the android softkeyboard on phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from airowe guided me in the right direction. This solution didn't seem to work for Android 2.3.X devices (the soft keyboard would still pop up). So I tweaked it a bit.
I ended up using the following code:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0); //hide keyboard

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
{
   editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
}
else
{
   editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
}
```

This would probably allow pre-honeycomb tablets to enter text. However I think this is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

use

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(fieldController.getFieldComponent().getWindowToken(), 0); //hide keyboard
```

to hide the keyboard.

Then, you can set the input type to what you want.

i.e.

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```