# How to hide keypad when editText is in focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, android-keypad

I want the editText box to be click-able so the user can scroll through the text, but I do not want the keyboard to appear.
I have tried all these but they do not do what I want:

In XML:

```
android:editable="false"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
android:inputType="none"
```

This disables it:

```
editText.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL);
```

This only works on API 21 and above:

```
editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

fallow the above link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8997725/1612065 Try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_file_url"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

***Use these lines of code***

```
  EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an edit text on touch listener. This will make the edit text untouchable because it is set to return true.

```
   EditTextHere.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          return true;
        }
    });
```

Make a statement that it will allow the user to touch edit text by returning it to false.