# How to completely hide the virtual keyboard in all EditTexts?

Tags: android

I am developing an android app where most users use a hardware keyboard attached to the android device for easy character input.

Even though the hardware keyboard is present, when user clicks on an `EditText`, the virtual keyboard pops up which is unnecessary.

I need to give the user a setting to completely disable the virtual keyboard so they can use the hardware keyboard alone.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997225/how-to-hide-android-soft-keyboard-on-edittext) question has several answers on how to disable soft keyboard for a single `EditText`, but conditionally disabling soft input for inividual `EditText`s is quite difficult for me since there are large number of activities which contain `EditText`s.

One way to do is to install `Null Keyboard` app and select it as the virtual keyboard from android settings as described [here](https://www.wikihow.tech/Hide-the-Keyboard-on-an-Android), but I don't want users of my application to rely on a third party application.

Is there a way to globally disable virtual keyboard without disabling it for individual screens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide Android soft keyboard on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997225/how-to-hide-android-soft-keyboard-on-edittext)

Comment: @RonTLV the answers in that question are focused on how to disable soft keyboard for a single `EditText` element. What I am looking for is a way to conditionally disable soft input in all `EditText` elements from a single place without changing code in each place I have used an `EditText` in the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable keyboard for all `EditTexts` You can create a custom `EditText` and disable keyboard functionality in it. And in your Project use your own custom `NoKeyboardEditText` instead of using Native `EditText`. Like

```
public class NoKeyboardEditText extends EditText {


    public NoKeyboardEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }


    public void init() {
        setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    }

}
```

Now in your XML, your can use your Custom `NoKeyboardEditText` in this way

```
<com.your_package_name.NoKeyboardEditText
 ... // add all other attributes here
/>
```

Or

I found another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18358708/5701085), have a look on it, if it solves your problem.

Comment: did it solve your problem? let me know if you have any further query.