# Prevent the keyboard from displaying on activity start

Tags: java, android, focus, android-keypad

I have an activity with an `Edit Text` input.  When the activity is initialized, the Android keyboard is shown.  How can the keyboard remain hidden until the user focuses the input?

Comment: in your manifest `<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" ...>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android on-screen keyboard auto popping up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496901/android-on-screen-keyboard-auto-popping-up)

Comment: How to use together with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`?

Comment: @János android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"

Comment: the answer in this comment, was the answer i'm looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23605510/6942602

Answer (score 449, accepted):

I think the following may work

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

I've used it for this sort of thing before.

Comment: Is there a way to set it to be a digits-only keypad? i.e. 12Key keyboard?

Comment: @MohamedKhamis input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);

Comment: Yes it still works. @SagarNayak why would you want to hide keyboard for `EditText`?:) This is to hide keyboard when activity starts which contains `EditText`

Comment: @Devealte 7 years later and it worked for me, did you place it in onCreate?

Comment: @Dymas Yes, and I just fixed it several months ago :)

Answer (score 196):

Try this -

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Alternatively,

1. you could also declare in your manifest file's activity -

```xml
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".Main"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
          >
```

2. If you have already been using `android:windowSoftInputMode` for a value like `adjustResize` or `adjustPan`, you can combine two values like:

```xml
<activity
        ...
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
        ...
        >
```

This will hide the keyboard whenever appropriate but pan the activity view in case the keyboard has to be shown.

Answer (score 34):

Hide it for all activities using the theme

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme">
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateHidden</item>
</style>
```

set the theme

```xml
<application android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

Comment: like this global approach.

Comment: This worked as i was using different themes at various places

Answer (score 24):

Add these two properties to your parent layout (ex: Linear Layout, Relative Layout)

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

It will do the trick :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, however setting them to `true` works, as per Jack T's answer. Was there a behavior change in recent versions?

Comment: In addition to my answer, you need to check the other properties as well which you have in manifest and for edit text.

Comment: I just have the most basic properties in them. I don't understand why setting these to `false` should work though, as the idea is to get the focus away from the EditText boxes.

Comment: Maybe it used to get the focus away from the EditText boxes by getting it away from the parent layout? But not anymore, it seems.

Answer (score 14):

Try to declare it in manifest file

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".HomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
```

Answer (score 14):

If you are using API level 21, you can use editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);

Answer (score 11):

Just Add in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".HomeActivity"  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also write these lines of code in the **direct** parent layout of the .xml layout file in which you have the "problem":

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ...
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        ...
        android:hint="@string/write_here" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_ok"
        ...
        android:text="@string/ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT :**

Example if the EditText is contained in another layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ... >                                            <!--not here-->

    ...    <!--other elements-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/theDirectParent"
        ...
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >        <!--here-->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/myEditText"
            ...
            android:hint="@string/write_here" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_ok"
            ...
            android:text="@string/ok" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ConstraintLayout>
```

The key is to make sure that the EditText is not directly focusable. 
Bye! ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Best solution for me, paste your class

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    super.onStart();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just add this in your manifest.xml file

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
```

You are all done.

Answer (score 4):

To expand upon the accepted answer by @Lucas:

Call this from your activity in one of the early life cycle events:

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);`

### Kotlin Example:

```
override fun onResume() {
  super.onResume()

  window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Function to hide the keyboard.

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();

    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

> Hide keyboard in AndroidManifext.xml file.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this set unique attribute for each element

```
TextView mtextView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
mtextView.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

Keyboard will not show while element is focus

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21516486)

Answer (score 1):

```
//to hide the soft keyboard
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this on your Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
           InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
           imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
      }
      return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare this code( android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden")
in manifest inside your activity tag .

like this :

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

Only this solution worked for me on **API 26** & Kotlin

```
   override fun onResume() {
    window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)
    super.onResume()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

or You can use focusable tag in xml.

android:focusable="false"

set it to false.[here is the snippet of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wpbM.png)