# Default text in the serach bar with AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm using the AutoCompleteTextView to allow users to search a from a list of countries. I want to have some default text preloaded in the search bar before the user clicks on it, such as "Search" or "Find Nearest Country". Is it possible to do this? If so how?

Right now, the app opens directly into the search box with the keyboard pulled up. Rather, I want the users to click on the bar before searching.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Answer (score 1):

A TextView's hint seems to be exactly what you need. See [`android:hint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ahint) for the XML attribute or [`setHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29) for the corresponding Java method.

To prevent the keyboard from popping as soon as your activity is entered, you should set the [`android:windowSoftInputMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) attribute in the activity declaration to `stateHidden`.

Comment: Awesome, the android:hint worked but it still opens up the application directly into the search bar with stateHidden and stateAlwaysHidden. Any idea why?

Comment: Strange, that solution always worked for us. Maybe try to set it directly on the window? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9732810/82788