# Remove focus from EditText and also keep it editable

Tags: android

I am using `EditText` but when `Activity` is started my `EditText` is already focused. I want to remove focus and also make it editable on click.

Here is the code of my edittext.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_HotelLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_edit_location_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create dummy layout as below which you should keep exactly above your EditText and then use nextFocusUp and nextFocusLeft as shown.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="0px"/>

        <EditText

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
             android:id="@+id/et"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/et"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/et"
            app:met_floatingLabel="normal" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following two properties in parent Layout of the Edit text

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

if your edit text is inside linear layout you can do like this

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:focusable="true"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_HotelLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_edit_location_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been responded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9732810/4681367)

> Try this also -
>   `this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`
>
> Otherwise, declare in your manifest file's activity -
>
> ```
> <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
>              android:label="@string/app_name">
> <activity android:name=".Main"
>      android:label="@string/app_name"
>      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
>      >
> ```