# How to disable the keyboard when I click on EditText?

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello I would like to do the next thing : when I click on an EditText I would like to hide the keyboard but seeing the cursor. I tried to do this :

```
    editText_test!!.setCursorVisible(false);
    editText_test!!.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    editText_test!!.setFocusable(true);
```

Obviously I don't see the keyboard but I can't click on my EditText. How can I do this ? To be precise I am using Kotlin.

Thank you !

Comment: see this answer..https://stackoverflow.com/a/45567180/7229971

Answer (score 12):

If you have minimum **API >= 21**:

```
editText_test!!.showSoftInputOnFocus = false
```

To deal with different versions:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    editText_test!!.showSoftInputOnFocus = false
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    editText_test!!.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
    editText_test!!.setTextIsSelectable(true)
} else {
    editText_test!!.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)
    editText_test!!.isFocusable = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a listener for your EditText's onFocus, you can add:

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);`

[How to avoid automatically appear android keyboard when activity start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732761/how-to-avoid-automatically-appear-android-keyboard-when-activity-start)

Comment: I try this : `editText_test!!.setOnFocusChangeListener(OnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

           
        })` but it does not work :/

Answer (score 0):

inside the listener method force the android to hide the virtual keyboard using the [hideSoftInputFromWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#hideSoftInputFromWindow%28android.os.IBinder,%20int%29) method in the [InputMethodManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html)

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: I tried this :  `editText_test!!.setOnFocusChangeListener(OnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
            val view = this.currentFocus
            if (view != null) {
                val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
            }
           
        })` but unfortunately it does not work when I click on the EditText I see the keyboard :/

Answer (score 0):

try this in manifest file

```
:
<activity
...
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
...
>
```