# How to hiding Android keyboard in kivy?

Tags: python, android, kivy, textinput

I have implemented a small numeric keyboard myself. The Android soft keyboard will pop up automatically when TextInput gets the focus, and I need to only respond to a custom keyboard or an external physical keyboard. How can I hide the Android soft keyboard?
Thank all

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49880101/1117696

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent the keyboard from displaying on activity start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732761/prevent-the-keyboard-from-displaying-on-activity-start)