# How do I display only the cursor but not the standard Android keyboard when i click on EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to set, in java code, my `EditText` so that, when i click will display only the `Cursor` but not the android standard keyboard. How can I do this?
Thanks

I EDITED:

I have an array of EditText:

```
for (i=0;i<N*N;i++) {
    value[i].setOnTouchListener(this);
    value[i].setOnClickListener(this);
    value[i].setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
}
```

and this method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    for (i =0 ; i < N*N; i++) {

        if(v == value[i]) {
        variable = 1;
        if(jey!=i) {
            jey=i;
            showDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    for (i =0 ; i < N*N; i++) {

        if(v == value[i]) {
        variable = 1;
        if(jey!=i) {
            jey=i;
            showDialog(CUSTOM_DIALOG);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) { 
    for (i =0 ; i < N*N; i++){
        if(v == value[i]) {
            variable =1;
            if(jey!=i) {
                jey=i;
                imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(value[jey].getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but in this way does not work I still see the standard keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Or use this:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

**Edit:**

This is a common solution I found on other threads:

```
public class NoImeEditText extends EditText {

     public NoImeEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
          super(context, attrs);     
     }  

     @Override      
     public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {   
          return false;     
     }        
}
```

Since this is my third try and I'm starting to feel stupid, I personnaly tested this time, and it works. Don't forget to also change the type in your layout, if you use one.

Comment: Refer to this solution then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841476/hiding-the-android-keyboard-for-edittext/10399125#10399125

Answer (score 0):

To apply it for one EditText (not for Activity how tell other answers), just provide hiding in focusChangeListener.

```
mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new CustomListener());
```

and CustomListener:

```
protected class CustomListener implements View.OnFocusChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

You can check `hasFocus` and hide only if it's true.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
/**
 * EditText which suppresses IME show up.
 */
public class DigitsEditText extends EditText {
    public DigitsEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setInputType(getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        final InputMethodManager imm = ((InputMethodManager) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE));
        if (imm != null && imm.isActive(this)) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final boolean ret = super.onTouchEvent(event);
        // Must be done after super.onTouchEvent()
        final InputMethodManager imm = ((InputMethodManager) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE));
        if (imm != null && imm.isActive(this)) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED) {
            // Since we're replacing the text every time we add or remove a
            // character, only read the difference. (issue 5337550)
            final int added = event.getAddedCount();
            final int removed = event.getRemovedCount();
            final int length = event.getBeforeText().length();
            if (added > removed) {
                event.setRemovedCount(0);
                event.setAddedCount(1);
                event.setFromIndex(length);
            } else if (removed > added) {
                event.setRemovedCount(1);
                event.setAddedCount(0);
                event.setFromIndex(length - 1);
            } else {
                return;
            }
        } else if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED) {
            // The parent EditText class lets tts read "edit box" when this View has a focus, which
            // confuses users on app launch (issue 5275935).
            return;
        }
        super.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution from @Lupsaa [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841476/hiding-the-android-keyboard-for-edittext/10399125#10399125):

Setting the flag textIsSelectable to true disables the soft keyboard.

You can set it in your xml layout like this:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText"
...
android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
```

Or programmatically, like this:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);

The cursor will still be present, you'll be able to select/copy/cut/paste but the soft keyboard will never show.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}

public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
view.requestFocus();
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
}
```

**When you want to show keyboard, just call *`(showSoftKeyboard())`* and when you want to hide keyboard, just call `(hideSoftKeyboard())`.**

**Then, just Add another same size layout on edittext and click event on it,then after you unable to click on edittext.**

> ```
>                <EditText
>                     android:id="@+id/etAnswer"
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>                     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>                     android:cursorVisible="false"
>                     android:inputType="number"
>                     android:maxLength="6"
>                     android:maxLines="1"
>                     android:paddingLeft="10dp"
>                     android:singleLine="true"
>                     android:textSize="20sp" />
>
>                 <LinearLayout
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>                     android:onClick="onClick" />
> ```

Answer (score -1):

```
add android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" in manifestfile to the activity
```