# Android: how to prevent software keyboard shown but with cursor visible?

Tags: android, user-interface

Standard software keyboard which is shown for any focused `EditText` takes too much space. I have to create my own built-in software keyboard right in the app and i need to prevent default software keyboard shown for the control. I'm using `editor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)` but cursor is hidden too.

How to prevent software keyboard shown but with cursor visible?

Comment: Does this help you in any way?
I am not into android but this is what had helped me once.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586354/android-hide-soft-keyboard-from-edittext-while-not-losing-cursor

Comment: The Question is a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/q/13586354/7550472](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13586354/7550472). The answer to this is to set the flag `textIsSelectable` in EditText to **true**. For more detail, check the detailed answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42180201/7550472

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Hide Soft Keyboard from EditText while not losing cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586354/android-hide-soft-keyboard-from-edittext-while-not-losing-cursor)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the software  keyboard shown , you could include             android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" in your project's AndroidManifest.xml within activity tag in which you would want to hide the keyboard.

Comment: How to apply this for `EditText`?

Comment: I used this in the activity where I had two edittext controls. It hid the software keyboard from both.Is it the same case in yours or you got to remove it from one of those?

Comment: yes, i need to set it separately, not for the while activity

Answer (score 0):

You can make cursor visible using editText.setCursorVisible(true) method.

Comment: cursor is now showing even if `setCursorVisible(true)` after 'setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)'