# how to hide virtual keyboard on edittext click

Tags: android

i have an activity in which i have an edittext.
On click on edittext i want to open TIMEPICKER DIALOG. I had written the code for it and its working.
The problem is that when i start the activity and click on edittext for first time-the virtual keyboard opens however for subsequent click on edittext TIMEPICKERDIALOG opens.
I do not want virtual keyboard to open even for first time.I want TIMEPICKER DIALOG to open every time.
Please help

Here is my code for timepickerdialog to open on edittext click

timeText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

```
      timeText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(RemindDetail.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                        timeText.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                        calender[3]=selectedHour;
                        calender[4]=selectedMinute;
                    }
                }, hour, minute, false);//Yes 24 hour time
                mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                mTimePicker.show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1

Comment: i want only timepicker dialog which is set by me to open on edittext click

Comment: [http://www.yogeshblogspot.com/android_timepickerdialog/](http://www.yogeshblogspot.com/android_timepickerdialog/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set this property in your edit text

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: @AndroidWarrior: Thanks, but cursor is not showing. How to include cursor but not keyboard? edit: found the answer [here....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586354/android-hide-soft-keyboard-from-edittext-while-not-losing-cursor)

Answer (score 0):

Hi few days before I was facing the same problem. Then I used `onTouchListener` on `EditText`. What it does. it will open your datepicker when someone touch the `EditText.` use onTouchListener rather then `onClickListener` on EditText.

you can use this code. which I develop for android xamarin change it for android java. and Extend `View.IOnTouchListener`

```
 DOB.SetOnTouchListener (this);


 protected override Dialog OnCreateDialog (int id)
    {

        if (id == DATE_DIALOG_ID) {
            return new DatePickerDialog (this, HandleDateSet, _date.Year,
                _date.Month - 1, _date.Day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    void HandleDateSet (object sender, DatePickerDialog.DateSetEventArgs e)
    {
        _date = e.Date;

        DOB.Text = _date.ToString ("d");
    }



public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up) {
            ShowDialog (DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
        return true;

    }
```

hope it might help you.

Answer (score -2):

Just set the `EditText` property like `android:focusable="false"` in your xml.