# Hide soft keyboard works for one EditText but does not work properly for the other

Tags: android, keyboard

I have two EditText in my actvity_main, clicking on it I want to disable the soft keyboard of the android. To achieve this functionality, I was following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586354/android-hide-soft-keyboard-from-edittext-while-not-losing-cursor).

The two EditText has following id assigned to it

```
firstText and secondText
```

This is the code I applied to both the editText

```
firstText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (imm != null) {
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }                
            return true;
        }
    });
```

For secondText only the name changes. For both the EditText soft keyboard does not show. Which is exactly what I want, But I want the cursor too. In which case, firstText does not show the keyboard but has the cursor. for secondText I am not able to retain the cursor.

I tried printing values inside if condition and setOnTouchListener. They both works perfectly all right.

Can someone help me on where I am going wrong?

Thanks! in advance