# Android - Insert text at cursor position in EditText using custom keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-cursor

I have a custom keyboard, fixed on screen, that edits an `EditText`.

```
 myKeyboard.setListener(new CustomKeyboard.KeyboardListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(char key, String value)
        {
            myEditText.setText(value);
        }
```

I have disabled the default keyboard using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586354/android-hide-soft-keyboard-from-edittext-while-not-losing-cursor), which works perfectly.

The only problem is that, when I move the cursor inside the `EditText`, whatever I type is added to the end of the string, not considering the cursor position, which moves again at the start of the `EditText`.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try **getSelectionEnd()** method of EditText

```
myEditText.getSelectionEnd();
```